Strange MySQL Deadlock
I have a queue system where the design can be summarized as these tables -

queue

every new item goes to this table, a service keep reading this table to process the data


"log_yyyyMMdd"

every processed queue item will be moved to daily archive table


summary

every hour a summarizing task kicks in, grouping data from daily log table into this summary table
for reporting purpose



And here's explanation for data movement

From table 1 to 2, the process is
i.   start transaction
ii.  insert into log_yyyyMMdd (columns) select columns from queue where id = 123
iii. delete from queue where id = 123
iv.  commit

From table 2 to 3, the process is
i. insert into temp_table (summarized_columns) select summarized_columns from log_yyyyMMdd union all select summarized_columns from queue where date = yyyyMMdd
ii. start transaction
iii. delete from summary where date = yyyyMMdd
iv. insert into summary (summarized_columns) select summarized_columns from temp_table
v. commit


The temp_table was introduced so that it is not part of any transaction lock, to prevent step 2.i from interfering with step 1.ii causing deadlock, however the unfortunate still happens
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2024-05-05 06:10:14 0x7f5062220700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION xxx, ACTIVE 14 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 43518, OS thread handle 139982692251392, query id 4737203875 ... Sending data
    INSERT INTO log_20240502 
    (...) 
    SELECT ...
    -- This is query 1.ii
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3456 page no 12297 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table `transactions`.`log_20240502` trx id xxx lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 39; compact format; info bits 0
 0: ...

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION yyy, ACTIVE 16 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
14101 lock struct(s), heap size 1269968, 519680 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 43548, OS thread handle 139983220508416, query id 4737203109 ... Sending data
    INSERT INTO summary_automated_temp (...)
    SELECT ...
    FROM log_20240502 
    ...
    -- This is query 2.i
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3456 page no 12297 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table     `transactions`.`log_20240502` trx id yyy lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

 -- UPDATED WITH MORE LOGS BELOW

 Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 39; compact format; info bits 0
 ...

 Record lock, heap no 51 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 39; compact format; info bits 0
 ...
 
 *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
 RECORD LOCKS space id 3366 page no 59172 n bits 112 index PRIMARY of table `transactions`.`queue` trx id 421459371442864 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
 Record lock, heap no 41 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 42; compact format; info bits 0
  0: len 30; hex      30623936613266302d373133342d343465632d383364622d363330306535; asc 0b96a2f0-7134-44ec-83db-6300e5; (total 36 bytes);

Anyone could suggest how to overcome this? By the way innodb_lock_wait_timeout is set to 50, but according to log, deadlock happens just after 10+ seconds of waiting.
I am also not sure if this is "Deadlock" situation or "Lock wait timeout" situation, it looks timeout to me, but MySQL seems to consider this a deadlock

If transactions mutually hold locks preventing each other from progressing, that's a deadlock. If mysql detects such a scenario, then will raise deadlock error immediatelly and will not wait for lock timeout to elapse. The log excerpt clearly states this is a deadlock. There should be a waiting for section for the 2nd transaction as well.

@Shadow its strange, because 2nd transaction is not covered with "lock" or "start transaction", would normal query also try to put lock on rows?

@Shadow I just found the missing bit of logs for the "waiting for" for 2nd transaction

All tata modifications run in transactions, whether you explicitly specified one or not.

I cannot reconcile the deadlock error report with your data transfer process description. The error report say that transaction (2) is waiting for a S lock on the queue table. However, process 1 is the only one that touches queue table, so it cannot be process 1 deadlocking with process 2.

@Shadow apologies again, i just fixed 2.i with more details, that insert query actually consists of log table union queue table, in order to get full record of the day

Is the date column indexed in the queue table (single column index or being the leftmost column in a compound index)? Also, I do not get the point of the union with the queue table. How often do you move the completed items from queue to the log table?

yeah, date is indexed in the queue table, single column index applied. i'm doing union because the queue data may stay there for max 2 days, but queue data needs to be reflected into the report as well, hence i designed the query that way, so that summary table is combination of daily log table + queue data on the same day
